# Convert UIScrollView contentOffset and contentSize to layer position and bounds properties

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a `UIScrollView` displayed in fullscreen holding a `UIImageView` that fills the `contentView` of the scrollView. I added a method to register the `contentOffset` and the `contentSize` of the scrollview at a specific pan and zoom.

I'm trying to convert those coordinates to a `CALayer` that I can animate using the `position`  and `bounds` in order to animate a pan and zoom to the desired point.

How to convert the `contentOffset` and `contentSize` of a `UIScrollView` to a `CALayer` `bounds` and `position` properties. The CALayer is a screen sized `CALayer` and is add to another screen sized `CALayer`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I just had to ask the question to finally answer my own problem!

set the `anchorPoint` of the `CALayer` to `CGPointZero`

then set the `bounds` size to the `contentSize`

set the `position` to the negative `contentOffset` `{-contentOffset.x,-contentOffset.y}`

Finally.